# jQuery UI Drop placeholder with background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have several columns which are `<ul>` tags, every column has it's own background color and every column is sortable by jQuery UI. My problem is, I want to make drop placeholder with background color, custom border dimensions etc. But whichever color I set, background color of placeholder will be the same as background color of column where I want to drop it.
This is simple example of what I made:

```
<div class="wrap">
            <ul class="prvi">
                <li class="naslov">Naslov1</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="drugi">
                <li class="naslov">Naslov2</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="treci">
                <li class="naslov">Naslov3</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="cetvrti">
                <li class="naslov">Naslov4</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
                <li>Neki predmet</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
```

jquery file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul").sortable({containment : 'document', tolerance: 'pointer', cursor: 'pointer', 
    revert: 'true', opacity : 0.6, connectWith : "ul", placeholder: 'border', 
    items : 'li:not(.naslov)'}).disableSelection();
});
```

and css

```
...
.border{
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: lightgray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    color: white;
}

.prvi li{
    background-color: gray;
}

.drugi li{
    background-color: red;
}

.treci li{
    background-color: yellow; 
}

.cetvrti li{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I fixed your problem. You should use !important in background-color for your placeholder. Here is your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwBXX/

in your CSS make this:

```
.border{
border: 2px solid black;
background-color: lightgray !important /* when you add this problem solved */;
box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
color: white;
```

}

Now you can set any background-color you want and it will apply it.